# How do I obtain the ssh public key from my VSphere ESXi 5.1 host hypervisor residing in vcenter with puppet-enterprise cloudprovisioner

Tags: ssh, ssl, puppet, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I am using the learn puppet 3.1 vm and trying to connect to a host hypervisor. I followed the instructions to create a .fog file under root which includes a yaml hash, and I read that the yaml hash isn't discontinued until puppet 3.3 so my credentials should work, but when I run puppet node_vmware list it tells me that my I am missing the required arguments which should not be the case.

I am able to ssh into my host hypervisor via winscp and enter the shell using PuTTY, so I cannot seem to understand why its not returning the ssh pub key like it says it would in the puppet cloud provisioner instructions.

I read from [troubleshooting](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/trouble_cloudprovisioner.html), that:
"ENC Can’t Communicate with Nodes
As of Puppet Enterprise 3.0, SSL is required for all communication between nodes and the ENC. The --enc-ssl option has been removed."

Does this mean that I need to include ssl in my server domain name? it shouldn't be the case considering it doesn't specify so in the instructions included in: [cloudprovisioning](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/cloudprovisioner_configuring.html)

the format of my .fog file is exacly like that in the cloud provisioning link. Are there any changes or settings I need to make in VCenter to enable me to do cloud provisioning in puppet?